# mysql query takes about a minute using between

Tags: mysql

I have a query that joins four table but I can't understand why its taking about a minute. I know the date between is more than 3 years. I don't really know what to do and how to optimize this query for better performance. Can someone give me suggestion on what to do? Will attached the query and the explain of the query.

```
SELECT 
                `purchase_order`.`id`, 
                `customer`.`name` AS customer_name,
                `purchase_order`.`po_date`,
                `purchase_order`.`po_number`,
                `purchase_order`.`customer_id` AS customer_id ,
                `customer`.`name` AS customer_name, 
                `purchase_order`.`status` AS po_status, 
                `purchase_order_items`.`product_id`, 
                `purchase_order_items`.`po_item_name`, 
                `product`.`weight` as product_weight,
                `product`.`pending` as product_pending,
                `product`.`company_owner` as company_owner,
                `purchase_order_items`.`uom`, 
                `purchase_order_items`.`po_item_type`,
                `purchase_order_items`.`order_sequence`, 
                `purchase_order_items`.`pending_balance`, 
                `purchase_order_items`.`quantity`, 
                `purchase_order_items`.`notes`, 
                `purchase_order_items`.`status` AS po_item_status,
                `purchase_order_items`.`id` AS po_item_id 
              FROM  purchase_order
          INNER JOIN customer ON `customer`.`id` = `purchase_order`.`customer_id`
          INNER JOIN purchase_order_items ON `purchase_order_items`.`po_id` = `purchase_order`.`id` 
          INNER JOIN product ON `purchase_order_items`.`product_id` = `product`.`id`  WHERE  
                    `purchase_order_items`.`product_id` = '121' AND
                    `purchase_order`.`po_date`  
                    BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2019-02-28' AND
                    `purchase_order_items`.`status` IN('Pending','Incomplete') 
               ORDER BY `purchase_order`.`po_date` DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

Im also not sure what to do about the explain and Im still trying to understand why its like this and how can i optimize the query. I hope someone could help me on this.

[image]

Comment: It looks good. Do you have indexes on the id fields? It helps a lot.

Comment: With that SQL you'd assume it would use the purchase_order as a base, but somehow it uses the customer table?  Does it run faster if you LEFT JOIN the customer table? (you only need it for the Name anyway)

Comment: "It looks good" well it doesn't @cdm "Using temporary; using filesort" is actually the worst case.. Topicstarter well optimizing a query with joins and a ORDER BY DESC can be tricky to optimize ideally MySQL should access the table first on which you order to avoid "Using temporary; using filesort"

Comment: By the way questions about preformance should include `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table>` output for every table involved in the query...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your query is good.  Rewritten using alias names for tables for shorter yet still readable "po" vs "purchase_order",  "poi" vs "purchase_order_items"

Your purchase_order table should have an index at a minimum on date THEN id.  So your WHERE clause can optimize based on the date, but also have the po.id as a basis to JOIN to your purchase order items table by id.

Next, the purchase order items, would help with an index on ( po_id, product_id, status ) to help optimize that join criteria.

```
Purchase_Order index (po_date, id )
Purchase_Order_Items index ( po_id, product_id, status )

SELECT 
        po.id, 
        c.name AS customer_name,
        po.po_date,
        po.po_number,
        po.customer_id AS customer_id ,
        c.name AS customer_name, 
        po.status AS po_status, 
        poi.product_id, 
        poi.po_item_name, 
        p.weight as product_weight,
        p.pending as product_pending,
        p.company_owner as company_owner,
        poi.uom, 
        poi.po_item_type,
        poi.order_sequence, 
        poi.pending_balance, 
        poi.quantity, 
        poi.notes, 
        poi.status AS po_item_status,
        poi.id AS po_item_id 
    FROM 
        purchase_order po
            INNER JOIN customer c
                ON po.customer_id = c.id
            INNER JOIN purchase_order_items poi
                ON po.id = poi.po_id 
                AND poi.product_id = '121' 
                AND poi.status IN ('Pending','Incomplete') 
                INNER JOIN product p 
                    ON poi.product_id = p.id  
    WHERE 
        po.po_date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2019-02-28' 
    ORDER BY 
        po.po_date DESC 
    LIMIT 
        0, 20
```

If that doesn't help, Your order of tables appears ok but the engine might be trying to think too much for you.  You can try adding additional keyword "STRAIGHT_JOIN" (specific to mysql).

```
select STRAIGHT_JOIN ( ... rest of query )
```

This tells mySQL to run the query in the table order I gave you.

Comment: Like i said in the comments ideally MySQL should ideally access the table with ORDER BY column first this query enforced that.. It is indeed true that `STRAIGHT_JOIN` might work i also adviced using it untill i found out there are downsides to using `STRAIGHT_JOIN` when no values where found.. A INNER JOIN would trigger a  "Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables" where the `STRAIGHT_JOIN` would scan the complete index (file) annyway.